# MethodReturnObject: Antipattern? How to refactor it?

Tags: design-patterns, anti-patterns

In a project that I joined recently we have a class that looks like this:

```
class MethodReturn {
  public int    status    = C_OK
  public string message   = ""
  public string str_value = ""
  public int    int_value = 0
  public double dbl_value = 0
  // and some more

  // also some methods that set/get these values
}
```

This class is used almost everywhere as a return type. So method signatures look like this:

```
public MethodReturn doSomething( int input, int output )
```

And the calling code looks like this:

```
returnObj = doSomething( input, output )
if( returnObj.status != C_OK ) return returnObj

returnObj2 = doSomethingElse( input2, output2)
if( returnObj2.status != C_OK ) return returnObj2
```

The `MethodReturn` object is claimed to be "genius", but to me it looks like an antipattern, since it hides the actual functionality of the code and adds a lot of overhead to the code, that could be handled much better by Exceptions. 
Also I consider the manipulation of an Argument as a side effect that SHOULD be avoided.

Unfortunately those `MethodReturn` objects are given to the GUI to display the result of an operation or show a message when an error occurs.

So, is there an actual name for this "pattern"? Is it just a code smell that you could live with, as long as you stay consistent with it? Or should I try to refactor that object out of the project to avoid heavy problems in the future? Which specific problems could be named that relate to this pattern?

PS: The code above pseudo code, we actually code in VB.NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I should say that this question is largely opinion based and you should not expect to get a definitive answer. Having said that, here is my opinion.

**Error codes vs Exceptions**

Neither error-code-based nor exception-based approach is perfect. And this is the reason why even today some high-level languages still don't have exceptions (see Go for a fresh example). Personally I tend to agree with Raymond Chen's article ["Cleaner, more elegant, and harder to recognize"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050114-00/?p=36693) that if proper error handling of all errors is of utmost importance, it is easier to write correct error-code handling than correct exception-based code. There is also an article with similar argument by ZeroMQ author ["Why should I have written ZeroMQ in C, not C++ (part I)"](http://250bpm.com/blog:4). AFAIU the main point of both articles is that when you use error-codes-based approach, usually it is easier to see when a piece of code doesn't handle errors properly because of better locality of error-handling code. With exceptions you often can't see if some method call can raise an exception but it is not handled (without analyzing the code of the whole call hierarchy). Actually this is why "checked exceptions" were added to Java but it achieved only a limited success because of various design limitations.

However error-codes are not free and one side of the price you pay is that you typically should write more code. In many business applications 100% correct error handling is not that important and it is often much easier to get "good enough" code using exceptions. This is why many business applications are written using exception-based languages and frameworks.

Generally to me this is similar to garbage collector vs manual memory management decision. In some contexts you really should use error codes or manual memory management but for the most of the use cases exceptions and GC are good enough.

**Particular code**

Even though I consider Error codes vs Exceptions to be an open question and a design decision that should be made basing on particular project context and goals, I really don't like the code you've shown in your question. The thing that I really don't like is that there is single `MethodReturn` that contains all possible return types. This is a bad thing because it hides from the developer the real method return type.

If I wanted to use error-codes in .Net, my first idea would be to use "out parameters" in a way similar to what standard [Double.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) do. Obviosuly you can use some more complicated return type than just plain `Boolean` to return more details about error (such as error code + message). Again this approach has some pro and cons. The biggest con to me is that VB.NET unlike C# doesn't explicitly support `out` (only `ByRef` which is two-sided) so it also might confuse developer about what's really going on.

My second approach would be to use generic wrapper class similar to the one you've shown to encapsulate all error-related things but not the return value. Something like this (I'll use C# as I'm much more familiar with it):

```cs
class MethodReturn<TValue> {
  private readonly int    _status;  
  private readonly string _errorMessage;
  private readonly TValue _successValue;

  private MethodReturn(int status, string errorMessage, TValue successValue) {
        _status = status;
        _errorMessage = errorMessage;
        _successValue = successValue;
  }

  public static MethodReturn<TValue> Success(TValue successValue)  {
      return new MethodReturn(C_OK, null, successValue);
  }

  public static MethodReturn<TValue> Failure(int status, string errorMessage)  {
      return new MethodReturn(status, errorMessage, default(TValue));
  }

  public int Status { get { return _status; } }
  public string ErrorMessage { get { return _errorMessage; } }
  public int SuccessValue { get { return _successValue; } }

  public bool IsSuccess {
      get {
          return _status == C_OK;
      }
  }
}
```

If I wanted to be more pedantic, I might also raise an exception if `SuccessValue` is accessed when `IsSuccess` is `false` and if `ErrorMessage` is accessed when `IsSuccess` is `true` but this might also become a source of a lot of false positives.

And if you want to go functional, you may notice that this class is actually almost a [Monad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)) similar to [Scala `Try`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Try.html) which is a special case of `Either` monad defined in [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/util/Either.html) and [Haskell](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/category-extras-0.52.0/docs/Control-Monad-Either.html) or similar [Result](https://fsprojects.github.io/Chessie/reference/chessie-errorhandling-result-2.html) from Chessie F# library. So you can extend this class with `map` and `flatMap` and use them to do some monad composition but I suspect that in VB.NET syntax that would look ugly.

It might make sense to switch from simpler `Try` to more generic `Either` if you have only a few different contexts with distinct error codes lists that you want to encode in the type system and thus make error handling code safer (see [this F#/Result article](http://blog.leifbattermann.de/2016/04/09/functional-error-handling-in-fsharp-by-example/) for an example).

Comment: Your answer actually provides all the information i needed to build my own oppinion on the topic. Thanks for that. :)

During the last three days 3 possibilities crossed my mind: 
(1) Making MethodRetrun a generic like in your example. 
(2) returning simthing like `Tuple<ReturnMethod, ResultType>` 
(3) making MethodReturn the outvariable since it needs to be changed regularly and i could still use something like method chaining.